# Comparar fechas como string en PHP

Tags: php, apache, datetime, date

Estuve intentando comparar dos fechas simples en forma de **string** en **php** con el formato "Año-mes-día". La única forma con la que lo conseguí hacer fue la siguiente:

```php
<?php
$a="1901-03-12";
$b="2000-04-11";

$a=strtotime($a);
$b=strtotime($b);

if($a > $b){
   echo "MAYOR";
} elseif($a == $b) {
   echo "IGUALES";
}else{ 
   echo "MENOR";
}

?>
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra forma de realizar lo anterior respetando el formato del string "Año-mes-día".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Puedes** hacer estas cosas:

- Pasar a cada una de las fechas como parámetro de la clase `DateTime()` que devuelve un nuevo objeto de tipo [DateTime]((https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.construct.php) opción
- Usar operadores ternarios para acortar las líneas de código de 7 a 1
- Observa que la segunda parte de mi operador ternario la envuelvo entre paréntesis para evaluar 2 condiciones aparte de la primer condición que esta al inicio
- Como punto final puedes dejar de usar la función `strtotime()`

Quedando tu código así

```
<?php

$a= new DateTime("1901-03-12");
$b= new DateTime("2000-04-11");

$res = ($a > $b) ? "mayor" : (($a < $b) ? "menor" : "igual");

echo $res;
```

También **opcionalmente** tienes el uso de [format->()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php) para indicar el formato que debe tener el parámetro pasado a dicha función; quedando de este modo

```
$a->format('Y-m-d');
$b->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el formato que necesitas es **Y-m-d** la comparación como texto la puedes hacer de forma directa, no necesitas ningún tipo de conversión:

```
<?php

$a = "1901-03-12";
$b = "2000-04-11";

// $a=strtotime($a);
// $b=strtotime($b);

if ($a > $b) {
    echo "$a MAYOR $b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "$a IGUAL A $b";
} else {
    echo "$a MENOR $b";
}
```

Puedes verificarlo [aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2d7e507b656ff6051179ea534af1da62808dc92)